# Set-cookie header not available in javascript even if SameSite=None is set

Tags: javascript, cordova, cookies, drupal, cross-domain

I am trying to authenticate to a Drupal backend from a Cordova app. I have installed [Cookie Same Site support](https://www.drupal.org/project/cookie_samesite_support) in order to have `SameSite=None` in the `Set-Cookie` header. From my app I do the following:

```
async function login() {
    const response = await fetch("http://www.example.com/drupal/user/login?_format=json",
        {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: 'my_username',
                pass: '...'
            })
        }) ;
    const content = await response.json() ;
    response.headers.forEach((value, key) => console.log(`${key} => ${value}`)) ;
    console.log("content" + JSON.stringify(content)) ;
}
```

In the console I see

```
cache-control => must-revalidate, no-cache, private index.js:49:54
content-language => it index.js:49:54
content-type => application/json index.js:49:54
expires => Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT index.js:49:54
content{"current_user":{"uid":"7","roles":["authenticated"],"name":"my_username"},"csrf_token":"bpLzMVp_[...]sQM","logout_token":"9TO-gfUE[...]T7RBHicru62Qey8"}
```

and in the network console

```
Set-Cookie: SESS6ddb039f0d9fe38fef2cae3b56a2a64f=1%2COLeo4LC4OFibbgDinG8oZF3XWGm17ROsKSNJkBnmkTRJgD; 
expires=Sat, 07-Jan-2023 12:47:53 GMT; Max-Age=2000000; path=/; domain=.www.example.com; 
HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: SESS6ddb039f0d9fe38fef2cae3b56a2a64f-legacy=1%2COLeo4LC4OFibbgDinG8oZF3XWGm17ROsKSNJkBnmkTRJgD; 
expires=Sat, 07-Jan-2023 12:47:53 GMT; Max-Age=2000000; path=/; domain=.www.example.com; 
HttpOnly
```

So, I see no `set-cookie` in the response available to Javascript, in spite of the fact that the module *adds* a second instance of the header with `SameSite=None` set. This seems to be on purpose, since in `modules/contrib/cookie_samesite_support/src/Session/CookieSameSiteSupportSessionManager.php` I see

```
    if ($original) {
      if (stripos($original, 'SameSite') === FALSE) {
        $original .= '; SameSite=None';
      }

      // Add the original cookie as per new browser expectations back.
      header($original, FALSE);

      // Add the legacy cookie.
      $legacy = str_replace($name, $name . self::LEGACY_SUFFIX, $original);
      $legacy = str_ireplace('; SameSite=None', '', $legacy);
      header($legacy, FALSE);
    }
```

I don't understand the comment on "browser expectations"; still, I had the feeling that the double instance of the cookie may cause the problem, so I commented the second header. In this way in the response I got only the `Set-Cookie` with `SameSite=None`, but from the Javascript loop on headers I *still* do not obtain the `set-cookie` header.

I I have no further idea, any suggestion is highly welcome.

EDIT: Of course, I don't care to grab the cookie if I can attach it to the requests that follow – I tried to make a subsequent `POST` to the same site from my Javascript, and the cookie is NOT attached.

Comment: the `headers` property is a `Headers` object, which does not include the `Set-Cookie` header by default. This is because the `Set-Cookie` header is not a part of the response body, but rather a header that instructs the browser to set a cookie.

Comment: @Sachin, yes and no – it is so only because the cookie is set with `HttpOnly`. But I can get and use the cookie using `curl`, so I expected there would be a way to do so (hopefully in a secure way) in a cross site environment.